# Android Studio 4.1.1: Does not see option to "Export encrypted key for enrolling published apps in Google Play App Signing

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I am trying to opt in for `App signing by Google Play` one of the steps says I need to export my key from Android studio. I do not find that option in my Android studio version 4.0.1/ 4.1.1 for APK format. I see that option only for App Bundle format. Has anyone seen this behavior? Any solutions?